# %Invalid interface type and number in Cisco my vlans are 22 23 and 24

Tags: cisco

Router>en
Router#conf ter
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#int gig 9/0.22
%Invalid interface type and number
Router(config)#
Router#
%SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console

Router#conf ter
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#int g0/0
%Invalid interface type and number
Router(config)#int g0/22
%Invalid interface type and number
Router(config)#

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

At first do command

```
show ip interface brief
```

and check what interfaces you have.

Probably you are looking for commands:

```
int gi0/0.22
 encapsulation dot1q 22

int gi0/0.23
 encapsulation dot1q 23

int gi0/0.24
 encapsulation dot1q 24
```